# Were Spivak's Calculus or Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis translated to French?

Tags: soft-question

The title says it all. I had a lot of fun reading some original papers of Riesz in french (not my native language), and was trying to continue doing so with some books that interest me. However, I haven't been able to locate translations for neither Spivak's Calculus nor Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis. Any thoughts?

Comment: A French translation of Rudin [does appear to exist](https://books.google.com/books/about/Analyse_r%C3%A9elle_et_complexe.html?id=xMUUOwAACAAJ)

Comment: Rudin is precisely [here](https://www.dunod.com/sciences-techniques/analyse-reelle-et-complexe-cours-et-exercices-0). For Spivak I don't think so.

Comment: For Rudin, I confirm : I have had it in my hands...

Comment: Note that [Baby Rudin](https://www.dunod.com/sciences-techniques/principes-d-analyse-mathematique-cours-et-exercices-0) is also translated